# Excluding Basic Authentication In A Single View - Django Rest Framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

I set basic authentication in my setting.py as follows. Now I need a view that doesn't use basic authentication. How can I do it.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',),
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You simply need to set the `authentication_classes` on your view. Have a look at http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#setting-the-authentication-scheme for an example.

Edit:
To remove authentication, set the `authentication_classes` to an empty list. Don't forget to remove permissions as well since they usually rely on authentication.

Comment: I doesn't need authentication class for that view @Linovia

Comment: @nidhin which you can get if you set an empty `authentication_classes`

Comment: The point of View's authentication_classes is that it overrides the default configuration settings.

Comment: I tried that. authentication_classes = ( ). But I still get {"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."}. Error

Comment: You may also need to set your permissions classes to an empty list too.

Comment: Thanks. Both permission and authentication classes should be empty. It worked. @Linovia

Comment: `() is not a list nor a tuple. Try [] or (,) ` ,can you explain this in more detail?

Comment: I got it wrong and will delete the comment. Thanks for pointing out, got confused with the fact that `()` depends on the context. `('a')` is not a tuple while `()` is.

Answer (score 10):

To exclude a view from authentication, set `authentication_classes` and `permission_classes` to `[]`.

```
class SignupView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []

    def post(self, request):
        # view code
```