# How to prevent Django Rest Framework from validating the token if 'AllowAny' permission class is used?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Let me show you my code first:

In `settings.py`

```
....
DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
),
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
)
....
```

My `my_view.py`:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes((AllowAny,))
def say_hello(request):
    return Response("hello")
```

As you can see, I'm using Token Authentication to protect my other API's by default, but **when I add a token header** in `say_hello`, Django Rest Framework will also check if the token is valid or not, even when I add `AllowAny` permission class.

**My question is** how to make Django Rest Framework ignore checking the token if the token header is present in the `say_hello`?
and are there any security considerations for making this?

Thanks.

Comment: You seem to be mixing up authentication and authorization ..

Comment: @wim No I was not, but maybe my question is not clear enough, I'll update the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be mixing up **authentication** and **authorization**.

By using the `@permission_classes` decorator on your view, you have overridden the default authorization from settings.  But you still have the default authentication classes from settings.

Try adding also to your view another decorator, to bypass the `TokenAuthentication`:

```
@authentication_classes([])
```

Note that if you put this on a `POST` endpoint, your app is now vulnerable to nasty stuff like Cross-Site Request Forgery.

Comment: OMG that was simple and i feel bad for myself :))))))

Comment: BTW what is the different between using AllowAny and using an empty list in permission_classes?

Comment: There is no difference.  `AllowAny` is only there to be explicit (self-commenting code)

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33539606/excluding-basic-authentication-in-a-single-view-django-rest-framework) applies here as well.

If you don't want to check tokens for one view, you can add `@authentication_classes([])` to the view. That should keep the default in place for other views while treating this one differently.